# Problema con DatePickerDialog en android

Tags: java, android

hola buenas tengo un problema en mi DatePickerDialog,funciona perfecto  en otros proyectos , toma los colores de la app, pero en este proyecto necesito utilizar en los styles de la app 
lo cual hace fallar mi DatePickerDialog , me muestra un color verde, no entiendo como cambiarla teniendo el cuenta que utilizo noactionbar.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v==seleccione_fecha){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        dia = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        anio = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                fecha_elegida.setText(dayOfMonth+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year);
            }

        }
                ,anio,mes,dia);
        datePickerDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me gustaría poder cambiar ese verde a rojo, no entiendo por qué se pone verde sino tengo ningún color verde en toda mi app.

Comment: no me funciona me sale este errror. > Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageInstantRunResourcesDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip file 'C:\Users\Pcmattty\Desktop\MitosClub\app\build\intermediates\incremental\packageInstantRunResourcesDebug\zip-cache\7jLLI+FgWtgAdXBfzJxz3N7KWy8='.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la creación de tu DateTimePicker de esta forma para que tome el estilo :

```
new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.DialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
```

Y crea el estilo :

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/tucolor</item>
</style>
```